# django view based template problem with PermissionRequieredMixin

Tags: django, django-views

i'm new in Django. I'm trying to "override" a permission_required for inheriting view. Example:

```
class ValetView(PermissionRequieredMixin, View):
    permission_required = ('lav.add_valets')
```

this works fine. If I go to this view, it's works dependient on `/admin` setted permissions. But now, I need to separate permission in ADD and EDIT, so I created this view inheriting from base:

```
class ValetsEditView(ValetsView)
    ValetsView.permission_required = ('lav.edit_valets')
```

When I try to access any of two, it said: permission denied but I allow the user only edit feature, NOT add. How can I grant permission only for edit??

I hope it is understood. Thanks!

Comment: Just specify `permission_required = ('lav.edit_valets')`, so wihthout the `ValetsView.` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Willem said the problem lies with `ValetsView.permission_required`. This shoudl be simply `permission_required`. Full code is:

```py
class ValetView(PermissionRequieredMixin, View):
    permission_required = 'lav.add_valets'


class ValetsEditView(ValetsView)
    permission_required = 'lav.edit_valets'
```

That should now work for you. I've also removed the parenthesis around the permissions, as they were serving no purpose.

---

### Something you didn't ask for

The following would also have been valid, as Django supports specifying a sequence of tuples. Note the trailing `,` below, which is required to specify a tuple of a single value in Python:

```py
class ValetView(PermissionRequieredMixin, View):
    permission_required = ('lav.add_valets',)


class ValetsEditView(ValetsView)
    permission_required = ('lav.edit_valets',)
```

In your code you had `('lav.edit_valets')` (without a trailing `,`), which python does not interpret as a tuple, rather it just removes the parenthesis and sees it as the string `'lav.edit_valets'`. Just one of those little quirks.

Comment: i tried that before, but obviosly I was doing something wrong. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Your original code `ValetsView.permission_required = ('lav.edit_valets')` is *modifying* the parent view's `permission_required`. Change it to the following:

```
class ValetsEditView(ValetsView)
    permission_required = ('lav.edit_valets')
```